# If $C \subset X$ and $\mathcal{U} \subset X$ is open. Is $C \cap \mathcal{U}$ open in $C$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

In an exercise regarding connection, I came to the following problem, I am given $C \subset X$ and $\mathcal{U} \subset X$ is open (where $(X,d)$ is a metric space). And I could use that is $C \cap \mathcal{U}$ open in $C$. However I don't know if this is true. When trying to prove it, I found my self not being able to proceed.

Let $x\in C\cap \mathcal{U}$. I want to see that there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset C\cap \mathcal{U}$.

Now $C$ is open in $C$ so there exist an $\epsilon_1$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_1) \subset C$. However, I know that $\mathcal{U}$ is open in $X$ not necesairily in $C$ so Im not sure I could use a similar argument with an $\epsilon_2$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_2) \subset \mathcal{U}$ (To then take $\epsilon = min \{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\} $)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to use the subspace topology on $C$.  Thus, by definition, if $U \subseteq X$ is open, then with the subspace topology on $C$, $C\cap U$ is open in $C$.

Answer (score 0):

@Jaoquin,

It is open. For if you are considering $C$ as a subspace, then it inherits the metric topology on $X$ when considered as a subspace, i.e. a subset is open if it equals the intersection of an open set with the larger space $X$. Thus if $U$ is open in $X$, $C \cap U$ is also open in $C$.